# AND/OR in Thymeleaf if

Tags: java, spring, templates, thymeleaf

i want to check two lists (empty-check). How can i do that in Thymeleaf?
I tried the following `th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(teilmassnahmenAktiv) or not #lists.isEmpty(teilmassnahmenInaktiv)}"` but no success. How to that right?

Thank

Comment: Your condition seems correct. Did you have get any error?

Answer (score 0):

`th:if="${!#lists.isEmpty(teilmassnahmenAktiv) || !#lists.isEmpty(teilmassnahmenInaktiv)}"`

Here is the link to [their documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#lists)